# Bessel function and ODE.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

> Define the Bessel function $J_{0}$ by
>   $$J_{0}(x) = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{\cos xt}{\sqrt{1-t^{2}}}\mathrm{d}t.$$
>   Prove that $J_{0}'' + (\frac{1}{x})J_{0}' + J_{0} = 0$ for all $x > 0$.

The hint of my professor was to use the Leibniz Rule (permutation of partial derivatives), but I don't see how that can help. Can someone help me? I appreciate it!

Comment: Step 1 ... what did you get for $J_0'(x)$ ??

Comment: Integration by Parts

Comment: I tried to develop the calculations after differentiating the definition of $J_0$ under the integral sign and I could write the LHS of the equation as 
$$
\int_0^\pi \left[x\cos^2 \theta \cos (x\sin \theta) - \sin \theta \sin (x\sin \theta)\right] d\theta = 
\int_0^\pi \left[x\sin^2 \theta \cos (x\cos \theta) - \cos \theta \sin (x\cos \theta)\right] d\theta
$$,
but I have no idea how to proceed now...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use Leibniz rule

$$J''_{0}(x)+ J_{0}(x)= \frac{1}{\pi}\frac {d^2}{dx^2}\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{\cos xt}{\sqrt{1-t^{2}}}\mathrm{d}t.+\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{\cos xt}{\sqrt{1-t^{2}}}\mathrm{d}t$$
$$J''_{0}(x)+ J_{0}(x)= \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-1}^{1}\partial^2_x(\frac{\cos xt}{\sqrt{1-t^{2}}})\mathrm{d}t.+\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{\cos xt}{\sqrt{1-t^{2}}}\mathrm{d}t$$
$$J''_{0}(x)+ J_{0}(x)= \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{-t^2\cos xt}{\sqrt{1-t^{2}}}\mathrm{d}t.+\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{\cos xt}{\sqrt{1-t^{2}}}\mathrm{d}t$$
$$J''_{0}(x)+ J_{0}(x)= \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-1}^{1}{\sqrt{1-t^{2}}}\cos(xt)\mathrm{d}t.$$
Integrate by part
$$J''_{0}(x)+ J_{0}(x)= \frac{1}{\pi}\left |{\frac {\sqrt{1-t^{2}}}x}\sin(xt)\right |_{-1}^{1}+\frac{1}{x\pi}\int_{-1}^{1}\frac {t\sin(xt)} {{\sqrt{1-t^{2}}}}\mathrm{d}t.$$
$$J''_{0}(x)+ J_{0}(x)= \frac{1}{x\pi}\int_{-1}^{1}\frac {t\sin(xt)} {{\sqrt{1-t^{2}}}}\mathrm{d}t.$$
$$J''_{0}(x)+ J_{0}(x)=-\frac 1 xJ_{0}'(x) $$

Comment: Don't you need uniform convergence of the integrals to bring the differentiation inside?